# Odoo 10 with paypal integration not return paid status to confirm sale order?

Tags: python, paypal, odoo, odoo-10

I got the issue with Paypal integration with Odoo 10. After payment from paypal site, it cannot return to Odoo with confirmed status for Sale Order.
I have configured with test environment:

[image: This is credentials]

[image: This is pdt token]

This is the form Odoo submit to sandbox.paypal.com:

```
<form method="post" target="_self" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[1]" value="_xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[2]" value="jeff@ntstiresupply.com">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[3]" value="NTS Tire Supply, LLC: /">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[4]" value="/">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[5]" value="83.0">
            <input type="hidden" name="handling" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[6]" value="0.00">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[7]" value="USD">
            <input type="hidden" name="address1" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[8]" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="city" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[9]">
            <input type="hidden" name="country" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[10]" value="US">
            <input type="hidden" name="email" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[11]" value="sb-alu2m658701@business.example.com">
            <input type="hidden" name="first_name" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[12]" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="last_name" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[13]" value="abc">
            <input type="hidden" name="zip" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[14]">

            <input type="hidden" name="custom" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[16]" value="{&quot;return_url&quot;: &quot;/quote/31879/7a63e797-9cde-4c43-a4d9-d4736d1fc4e9&quot;}">
            <input type="hidden" name="return" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[17]" value="http://localhost:8069/payment/paypal/dpn/">
            <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[18]" value="http://localhost:8069/payment/paypal/ipn/">
            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/input[19]" value="http://localhost:8069/payment/paypal/cancel/">
            <button type="submit" width="100px" class="btn btn-primary">

                <span>Pay &amp; Confirm <span class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" data-oe-id="5080" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/form[1]/button[1]/span[1]/span[1]"></span></span>
            </button>
        </form>
```

But after payment, I click on Return Merchant ('/payment/paypal/ipn/') , Odoo log here with post data = {}.

> 2019-12-05 21:14:40,677 5648 INFO 20190725_2
>   odoo.addons.payment_paypal.controllers.main: Beginning Paypal DPN
>   form_feedback with post data {} 2019-12-05 21:14:44,484 5648 WARNING
>   20190725_2 odoo.addons.payment_paypal.controllers.main: Paypal:
>   answered INVALID/FAIL on data verification

I followed this post [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/10.0/ecommerce/shopper_experience/paypal.html) but it did not work.

So, did I misconfigured something?

Comment: Are you sure you want to show your credentials here?

Comment: I have edited :)

Comment: And the same error is still remaining on my Odoo Enterprise version 13, one year later...